# Public can't access Windows Server 2008 with Nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm using `nginx` version 1.6.2, my server is `Windows Server 2008`. I just want to enable public access to my server. It's done locally, in my desktop. My config is just as simple as this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
...
```

I'm very newbie in `nginx`, my questions is what is the checklist that I should done to make my `nginx` available in `Windows Server 2008` environment? `Firewall` is already checked to allow `nginx`.

With `Apache` it's no problem. And note that, my `nginx` is run perfectly when I access from local (remote server) at "localhost/" or "127.0.0.1/".

Comment: Are you sure port 80 from the outside is reaching your machine?

Comment: Yes, with Apache it's ok. I don't know why, is it about firewall or something that must be configured. In firewall, it's already set to allow nginx.

Comment: anything in the logfiles, is nginx actually loading? what if you use 'listen' with the machine ip address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then I realized there's nothing wrong with nginx, it's because of the firewall that cover its server.